# Opening a newly created File in Dart

Tags: file, dart

I am new to dart and am currently trying to create a file from a data String.
All looks good so far as the length is not 0. But when i open the file, it instantly closes again, no console output, no errors.

I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction, if any information is missing, please point it out and i will provide if possible.

```
  void createFile(data) async{
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;

    var file = new File(tempPath+widget.tileText);
    var sink = file.openWrite();
    sink.write(data.codeUnits);
    await sink.flush();
    await sink.close();
    print(await file.length());
    OpenFile.open(file.path);
  }
```

UPDATE: added `flush()` and await before `close()` - loading a little smoother now, but File still closes instantly

Update2: removed `create()` (was a misunderstanding on my part)
now getting console output when the File closes: `D/EGL_emulation(23235): eglCreateContext: 0xef02d650: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2`
Running i ton my phone gives no console log, instead a simple "Can't open File" from the viewing application,i doublechecked the Path, it looks ok and it exists

Comment: There are at least two problems in your code. 1. You are not calling `flush()` before `close()`. 2. Both `flush()` and `close()` returns `Future` which you should await on before doing anything with the file. Please read https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/IOSink/flush.html and https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/IOSink/close.html

Comment: @julemand101 thank you, i did not know about `flush()`! I edited the code in my original Post, the loading seems to be smoother now, but the file still closes instantly

Comment: I don't think you code make much sense. Why e.g. the `file.craete()` after you have written content to the file? Also, if you just have a String which you want to output to a file you should properly take a look at `file.writeAsString`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/File/writeAsString.html

Comment: Also, what is the purpose the `OpenFile` class and how do you detect the file is closed?

Comment: Should also add that your `file.length().then` is a async call so `print(len);` will be executed at some point later. If you want to run `print(len);` as part of your `createFile` you should do: `print(await file.length());`. This will execute the print before `OpenFile.open(file.path);` is running.

Comment: @julemand101 i added the `file.create()` because before it would always give me the length 0 (which i now realize was because i didn't have the `await` on `close()`

the `OpenFile` class comes from the `open_file` package, which is supposed to easily let me open a file with a standard application (in this case it's a PDF)
I detect the file is closing because i get a PDF View for about a second in my emulator but it closes again, now i'm also getting this output when it closes (this is new): `D/EGL_emulation(23235): eglCreateContext: 0xef02d650: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2`

Comment: @julemand101 my outline is that i get an encrypted String from a webserver that represents the content of a file (which could be .pdf, .jpg or anything, really) and i need to open it in this app, so just printing a string would sadly not do it for me

Comment: @julemand101 i tried running it on my Phone instead of an Emulator, the console log diappears, instead i get a simple "Can't open file" from any PDF viewing application. I doublechecked that the path really exists, which it does..

Comment: Well, if you data is already converted to a String there are a risk that the data is corrupted. So you should properly read the data as List<int> or similar so you can write the bytes as bytes instead of String codeunits which are not the same.

Comment: @julemand101 i guess i'll have to look into how that string i get is formed then, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So i found 2 problems and solved it now:

1. The path was missing a "/"
2. I didn't format the data right, i had to decode it and use `writeAsBytes()`, ditched the sink

now it's working

```
  void createFile(data) async{
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;

    var file = new File(tempPath+"/"+widget.tileText);
    await file.writeAsBytes(base64Decode(data));
    print(await file.length());
    OpenFile.open(file.path);
    print(await tempDir.exists());
    print(file.path);
  }
```